# Spring Cloud Zuul gateway 401 basic authentication

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm working on a Spring Cloud Zuul gateway to put in front of my spring boot application. 
I use basic authorization on the applications side.
When I do a call to the gateway with the proper authorization header I always get 401 Unauthorized

```
"status": 401,
"error": "Unauthorized",
"message": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
```

But when I do the request directly towards the application it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specifying `sensitive-headers` property without `Authorization` value in Zuul routes will forward the Authorization header towards the application.
By default it has hese values: `Cookie,Set-Cookie,Authorization`

```
bootstrap.yml:

zuul:
  ignoredServices: '*'
  routes:
    application:
      path: /application/**
      serviceId: application
      sensitive-headers: Cookie,Set-Cookie
```

More info:
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/zuul/filters/ZuulProperties.java#L118

Comment: In my particular case it was also necessary:
security:
    basic:
        enabled: false